# Puppeteer / Heroku - page.pdf page-break different when in local vs production environment

Tags: heroku, pdf-generation, puppeteer, chromium, headless-browser

I am attempting to generate a PDF of a page using Puppeteer.. in local development.. I am able to return the PDF with proper page breaks.. however in production (Heroku server) my PDF has page breaks in the middle of my content!

Here is the code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    })
    console.log('browser has been opened')
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 1056})
    await page.waitFor(1000)
    await page.emulateMediaType('screen')
    await page.waitFor(5000)
    console.log('about to create PDF - standby')
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
      format: 'Letter',
      printBackground: true,
      path: MY PATH
    })
    console.log('pdf created')
    await browser.close()
    console.log('browser closed')
  }
```

Things I have tried..

- changing the CSS to include the following..

```
@media print {
    .page {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

- speaking to the owner of the heroku / puppeteer buildpack to confirm it is not an issue there
  https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack/issues/59
- emailing collaborators from the PPTR github repo
- tested various different types of `page.emulateMedia()` and styling options

here is a screenshot of the weird page break for reference..
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31495981/72014061-2aba7000-322d-11ea-8334-1d1df80f41d5.png

Comment: puppeteer has some issues with @media print & page-break-after. For me method `page.emulateMediaType('print')` cause some issues. No errors at all but the puppeteer break a job.

Answer (score 1):

`puppyteer` can't use `page-break-<any>` css rules with `flexbox`. Rewrite your css without flexbox and `puppyteer` will use page-break as should